# How to block GtkEntry context menu

Tags: gtk, gtkentry

I find **GtkEntry** has a default **context menu**
But I really do not want it, how can I disable it
I googled but no effective way found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to just hide/unref/destroy the wigdet passed (the `GtkMenu` being spawned) within a signal handler hooked to `populate-popup`?

Another option would be to filter out all right click events by hooking up to `GtkWidget`'s (actually yout `GtkEntry` which is a subclass of `GtkWidget`) `clicked` signal and returning TRUE (for being handled)

Comment: I have tried to destroy GtkMenu in populate-popup handler, which causes Segmentation fault. <br/>  But the second way works, returning TRUE in button-press-event handler blocks the menu. Thanks so much.